# RowState property not changing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005

I have an table edit that won't save changes. It looks like the problem is that the RowState is not changing. The foreach loop is for debugging:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Validate();
        bs.EndEdit();
        dsEdit.Tables["broker"].GetChanges();

        DataTable dtOut = dsEdit.Tables["broker"];
        foreach (DataRow rOut in dtOut.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rOut.RowState.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(rOut["contactfax"]);
            rOut["contactfax"] = "change";
            Console.WriteLine(rOut.RowState.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(rOut["contactfax"]);
        }


        int n = sdaBkr.Update(dsEdit.Tables["broker"]);
        MessageBox.Show(n.ToString() + " record(s) saved.");

    }
```

The Console output is as follow::

```
Unchanged
fax number here
Unchanged
change
```

What can cause this? I don't see any unusual properties set in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here: [EndEdit on BindingSource updates DataTable, but rowstate still unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995559/endedit-on-bindingsource-updates-datatable-but-rowstate-still-unchanged)

Calling EndEdit on each row as

```
rOut.EndEdit();
```

fixes the problem, but I don't understand, and I don't see that in any documentation.