# c# datagridview changes not reflected in underlying bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

EDIT: I'm using a DataGridView bound to a BindingSource below, however when I edit a cell in the DataGridView, checking BindingSource.CurrentItemChanged shows the original value for that cell. Am I using BindingSource incorrectly? I thought the whole point was that it would reflect changes made by the bound controls.
My code is listed below, any help would be much appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class GuiProductMaintenanceForm : Form {
    private const int FORM_HEIGHT = 600;
    private const int FORM_WIDTH = 800;
    private BindingNavigator menu;
    private DataGridView grid;
    private BindingSource source;

    public GuiProductMaintenanceForm() {
        instComponents();
        posComponents();
        setProperties();
        addComponents();
    }

    private void instComponents() {
        this.source = new BindingSource(
            DataHandler.getProductData(), "Products");
        this.menu = new BindingNavigator(source);
        this.grid = new DataGridView();

    }

    private void posComponents() {
        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;

        this.menu.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
        this.grid.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos + this.menu.Height);
    }

   private void setProperties() {
        //controls
        this.menu.Size = new Size(FORM_WIDTH, 32);

        this.grid.Size = new Size(FORM_WIDTH, FORM_HEIGHT - this.menu.Height);
        this.grid.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.grid.DataSource = source;
        this.grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.grid.ReadOnly = false;
        this.grid.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(
            FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12);

        //this form
        this.Text = "Product Maintenance";
        this.ClientSize = new Size(FORM_WIDTH, FORM_HEIGHT);
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    private void addComponents() {
        this.Controls.Add(this.menu);
        this.Controls.Add(this.grid);
    }

}
```

DataHandler.GetProductData() just returns a DataSet with the data, but i'll include the code just to be safe.

```
public static DataSet getProductData() {
        MySqlConnection c = makeConnection(getDefaultConnStr());
        c.Open();
        string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Products";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, c); 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Products");
        return ds; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old but here is something for those that stumble across this.
I believe your DataEdit is in the Gridview and you are editing that cell and that will not be propagated to the binidngsource unless you call the endedit method on the DataGridView.

Look here [EndEdit on BindingSource updates DataTable, but rowstate still unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995559/endedit-on-bindingsource-updates-datatable-but-rowstate-still-unchanged)

and here [How to properly commit bindingSource changes to source DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769005/how-to-properly-commit-bindingsource-changes-to-source-db)

You might also check this out
[How to: Reflect Data Source Updates in a Windows Forms Control with the BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f61k6akt(v=VS.80).aspx)